# Database_cleaner issue. Not working

Tags: database-cleaner

My test_helper:

```
require "simplecov"
SimpleCov.start do
  add_filter "/factories/"
end

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'

require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'mocha/mini_test'
require 'minitest/pride'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
require 'support/factory_girl'
require 'database_cleaner'

DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
  # Setup all fixtures in test/fixtures/*.yml for all tests in alphabetical order.
  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
  def setup
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def teardown
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  def setup
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  def teardown
    reset_session!
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

My gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
gem 'database_cleaner',       '~> 1.4.0'
```

What am I doing wrong? I am running my tests and my unit and integration tests aren't running independently like they should. What should I do? What am I missing?

I tried looking up solutions but noting seems to be working. What am I missing?